# Galeria PHP no carga imagenes grandes. Problema con while

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, div, while

llevo horas dando vueltas a una galeria y no logro que me funcione, soy principiante en PHP Y agradeceria cualquier ayuda. Adjunto codigo debajo.

En la galeria hay miniaturas y al hacer click te lleva la foto grande.. El problema es que no se abren las imagenes grandes. La galeria se encuentra en la página de cada producto, donde cada uno tiene un ID y una carpeta propia, es decir , el producto 200 tiene la carpeta 200 donde hay las fotos grandes junto con una subcarpeta 'thumbs'.

Carpeta producto --> imagenes grandes.

Carpeta thumbs -->imagenes pequeñas.

Para mostrar las 2 carpetas desde PHP , entiendo que por lógica hay que abrir 2 directorios con opendir (carpeta producto y carpeta thumbs), por lo tanto habrá que hacer 2 whiles recorriendo las imagenes de cada directorio, pero no estoy seguro si el codigo esta bien, estan puestos seguidos ¿es correcto?

Como he dichos los thumbnails de la carpeta thumbs, se cargan, pero los del directorio de las fotos grandes, no. 
Este es el codigo de la galeria - En cambio, si en la ruta pongo una imagen.jpg tal cual en lugar de la variable $file2 entonces se carga la imagen grande.

He comprobado las rutas estan bien , intuyo que debe ser un fallo de lógica o cuestión de llaves... Espero haberme explicado. Gracias de antemano.

Codigo de producto.php (dentro de un div) :

```
<?php
$ruta = "img/content/producto/$_GET[id]/thumbs/"; // Indica ruta para thumbnails
$filehandle = opendir($ruta); // Abrir archivos
while ($file = readdir($filehandle)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $tamanyo = getimagesize($ruta . $file);

        $ruta2 = "img/content/producto/$_GET[id]/"; // Indica ruta para imagen grande
        $filehandle2 = opendir($ruta2); // Abrir archivos
        while ($file2 = readdir($filehandle2)) {
            if ($file2 != "." && $file2 != "..") {
                $tamanyo2 = getimagesize($ruta2 . $file2);
            }
        }
?>
```

Para mostrar la galeria:

```
     <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="img/content/producto/<?php echo $_GET['id']?>/imagen.jpg">
     <img src="<?php echo $ruta.$file ?>" width="200px" height="auto" style="float:left;"></a>
```

Para cerrar

```
    <?php
    }
}
closedir($filehandle); // Fin lectura archivos
closedir($filehandle2); // Fin lectura archivos
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si ya probó con lo siguiente, pero en el  intente concatenar la ruta

```html
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?php echo $ruta2.$file2?>">
```

Comment: sí probé, peor no funciona, sigue sin cargar las imagenes grandes. :(

Comment: Cual error le arroja el código al intentar ejecutarlo???

Comment: Notice: getimagesize(): Read error!  en esta  linea: $tamanyo2 = GetImageSize($ruta2 . $file2); Si muevo las llaves de cierre del while, duplica o triplica la galeria de miniaturas.

Comment: Saque $ruta2 = "img/content/producto/$_GET[id]/"; del while

Comment: pero necesito esa ruta2 para abrir el directorio y sacar las imagenes grandes

Comment: Pero no necesariamente declarar la ruta dentro de cada ciclo

Comment: disculpa quizas me perdi, pero la $ruta y $ruta2 estan declaradas antes del ciclo while, no? por cierto con la sugerencia del principio ( href="<?php echo $ruta2.$file2?>")  arroja error; en la misma linea: Warning: getimagesize(thumbs): failed to open stream:

Comment: y si pongo una imagen en  href="imagen.jpg" entonces la galeria funciona, pero solo carga la misma imagen grande para todas las miniaturas...

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien. Quieres presentar en una página una galería de imágenes pequeñas que se encuentran en una carpeta y darle como enlace a esas imágenes su correspondiente en otra carpeta.

Diré lo que he hecho para reproducir tu problema.

- He asumido que hay una carpeta llamada `uploads` y dentro de ella hay varias carpetas con un id numérico
- Para esta prueba nuestra carpeta será `uploads/200`, o sea, he asumido que nuestro id actual es 200. Eso luego lo cambias con el `GET`.
- Dentro de `uploads/200` hay otra carpeta llamada `thumb` donde se encuentran las imágenes pequeñas.

Comprendido eso, en vez de ponernos a manipular los archivos, **usaremos [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php) para determinar lo que hay en las carpetas**.

Usumimos que tanto en la carpeta `200` con en su respectiva carpeta `thumb` **sólo hay imágenes**. Si no es así, debemos entonces refinar la búsqueda que hacemos con `glob` para obtener sólo las imágenes.

Todo lo demás está comentado en el código.

Lo he probado en un escenario real y funciona. Crea imágenes pequeñas y cuando doy click en alguna de ella me lleva a la imagen grande.

```
<?php

/*----Cambiar esta parte por tus datos reales----*/

$id=200;  //Cambiarlo por el _$GET
$urlThumb = "uploads/$id/thumb/";
$urlGrande = "uploads/$id/";
//URL del tipo http://wwww.dominio.com  hasta antes de la carpeta de imágenes
$urlReal="http://www./";

/*---------------------------------------------*/


/*Creamos un array con todas las imágenes de ambos directorios*/
$arrThumb = glob($urlThumb.'*.*');
$arrGrande = glob($urlGrande.'*.*');

//print_r($arrThumb);
//print_r($arrGrande);

/*Variable para concatenar nuestro contenido HTML*/
$strHTMLThumb="";
foreach ($arrThumb as $k=>$v)
{
    /*src para el thumb y para las imágenes grandes*/
    $srcThumb=$urlReal.$v;
    /*quitamos la palabra thumb del directorio así obtenemos el directrio de las imagens grandes*/
    $srcGrande = str_replace('thumb/', '', $v);

    $strHTMLThumb.='<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="'.$srcGrande.'">
     <img src="'.$srcThumb.'" width="200px" height="auto" style="float:left;"></a>';
}

/*Imprimimos el resultado concatenado*/
echo $strHTMLThumb;

?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda! ahora funciona más o menos... Resulta que se muestran los thumbnails pero en grande, es decir al hacer click también se abren los thumbnails de la misma ruta uploads/$id/thumb/.   La idea es que al dar click se carguen las imagenes grandes del directorio uploads/$id/. La razón de la carpeta thumb es para aliviar el peso de imagenes al cargarse en la pagina. Previamente, tengo un script que al subir una imagen de producto, la redimensiona en 2; una grande (imagen.jpg) y otra en thumbnail (thumb_imagen.jpg). Si puedes corregirlo dime como darte una medalla de oro asegurada.

Comment: @MamenMaria entonces no era como lo exponías en la pregunta original. Leyendo la pregunta yo entendí lo siguiente: **(A)**. Carpeta con **imágenes grandes**, ejemplo para el id 200: **`uploads/200/`**. **(B)** Carpeta con las **imágenes pequeñas** correspondientes: **`uploads/200/thumbs`**. El código busca las imágenes pequeñas en (B) y determina sus URLS a las imágenes grandes quitando la palabra `thumbs` de la ruta. ¿Qué es lo que falla? ¿No será que tus thumbs son en realidad imágenes grandes? En la prueba a mi me funcionaba perfecto.

Comment: Exacto es tal como lo explicas, quizás no me expliqué bien al principio. (A). Carpeta con imágenes grandes, ejemplo para el id 200: uploads/200/. (B) Carpeta con las imágenes pequeñas correspondientes: uploads/200/thumbs.   En resumen; Al hacer click en la imagen pequeña abre la grande, pero lo que no entiendo es que tengo las imagenes de las carpetas que son diferentes.Con este script, se carga solo 1 imagen y  el thumbnail aunque se vea pequeño, pesa lo mismo en KB que la imagen grande. La intención es mostrar 2 tamaños ( en KB , no en px) de una foto, y por eso hay 2 carpetas, me explico?

Comment: https://provadecms.000webhostapp.com/galeria.php Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo con tu código que tengo en un servidor de prueba. Aqui cada imagen (grande y pequeña) solo se extrae del mismo directorio /thumbs.(ese es el problema) Deberian coger las imagenes de carpetas diferentes. Si te fijas la foto de los tulipanes amarillos, realmente es un thumbnail reducido, por eso se muestra en pequeño.(otro problema), Deberia cogerla del directorio de fotos grandes. Las demás son fotos grandes que pesan lo mimo en Kb dentro del thumbnail como la grande.

Answer (score 0):

Intente así, el  debe ir dentro del segundo while

```html
<?php
$ruta = "img/content/producto/$_GET[id]/thumbs/"; // Indica ruta para thumbnails
$filehandle = opendir($ruta); // Abrir archivos
while ($file = readdir($filehandle)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $tamanyo = getimagesize($ruta . $file);

        $ruta2 = "img/content/producto/$_GET[id]/"; // Indica ruta para imagen grande
        $filehandle2 = opendir($ruta2); // Abrir archivos
        while ($file2 = readdir($filehandle2)) {
            if ($file2 != "." && $file2 != "..") {
                $tamanyo2 = getimagesize($ruta2 . $file2);
                ?>
                <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?php $ruta2.$file2 ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $ruta.$file ?>" width="200px" height="auto" style="float:left;"></a>

     <?php
           }
        }

    }
}
closedir($filehandle); // Fin lectura archivos
closedir($filehandle2); // Fin lectura archivos
```

Comment: Gracias por intentarlo, peero al mover las llaves del primer while repite x 4 veces los thumbails y sigue sin mostrar la imagen grandes..

Comment: y da este error; 
Warning: getimagesize(imagen-grande.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory on line 209. Linea 209: $tamanyo2 = GetImageSize($file2); Confirmo que las fotos grandes están.